# check associative array contains value

Tags: php

```
    Array (    
    [0] => Array ( 
               [questionID] => 47
               [surveyID] => 51
               [userID] => 31 
               [question_Title] => Choose Any One? 
               [question_Type] => Dropdown 
               [response] => 1.Android 2.Windows 3.Blackberry 
               [required] => 0 
               [add_time] => 0
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
               [questionID] => 48 
               [surveyID] => 51 
               [userID] => 31 
               [question_Title] => Is it? 
               [question_Type] => Bigbox 
               [response] => Yes No 
               [required] => 1 
               [add_time] => 0 
    )    
    [2] => Array ( 
               [questionID] => 129 
               [surveyID] => 51 
               [userID] => 31 
               [question_Title] => sELECT 
               [question_Type] => Single 
               [response] => DFG HBK GHCK HK 
               [required] => 0 
               [add_time] => 0 
    )
)
```

this is my multidimensional

Now i want to initially check array contains [required] => 1 or [required] => 0

i don't want to traversing array

Comment: Try arrayname[0]['required']

Comment: do you want to check this for every sub array? clearify your intention

Comment: niyou,yes!i  want to check this for every sub array

Comment: and what do you want to do if you have checked this for one sub array? come on talk to us - not just yes or no

Comment: niyou,i want  check condition where if subarray contains required=1

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your array name is `$myarray`

So you can do something like this -

```
foreach($myarray as $arrelement)
{
    if(isset($arrelement[required]) && $arrelement[required] == 1) //choose 1 or 0 in code as per your need
    {
         //traverse your array and do needful
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($yourArr[0]['required']==0)  //Just check for first element in your array
  echo "Zero";
else
  echo "One";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($mainarray as $array ){ //check for each 
  if($array['required']==1)
   //doSome Task
  if($array['required']==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most hackish solution I'll come up with all this morning, but if you are shooting for a quick one-liner, this should do:

```
if(in_array(1, array_column($myArray, 'required')))
   echo 'required';
```

*Edit: This assumes you've got PHP 5.5+ at hand*

**Update:** After a closer look at the documentation of [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array), this should be possible:

```
if(in_array(array('required' => 1), $myArray))
    echo 'required';
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, my way independent of the array structure (assume $x holds your data structure):

```
if (preg_match('/"required":[01]/',json_encode($x))) {
    // The array structure contains "required" => 0 or "required" => 1
} else {
    // Negative
}
```