# checking array multidimensional array contains value or not

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**my multidimensional array is**

```
Array (    
            [0] => Array ( 
                       [questionID] => 47
                       [surveyID] => 51
                       [userID] => 31 
                       [question_Title] => Choose Any One? 
                       [question_Type] => Dropdown 
                       [response] => 1.Android 2.Windows 3.Blackberry 
                       [required] => 0 
                       [add_time] => 0
            )
            [1] => Array ( 
                       [questionID] => 48 
                       [surveyID] => 51 
                       [userID] => 31 
                       [question_Title] => Is it? 
                       [question_Type] => Bigbox 
                       [response] => Yes No 
                       [required] => 1 
                       [add_time] => 0 
            )    

        )
```

then using foreach loop i submit each value and insert it in MySQL db
but if `[required] => 1` exist in array  i don't want to submit any values

so,how to check weather whole array  conatins  [required] => 1

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you googled the problem? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search?lq=1

Comment: thanks @i alarmed alien

Comment: possible duplicate of [check associative array contains value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988258/check-associative-array-contains-value)

Answer (score 0):

Seems a simple enough foreach loop will do the trick:

```
foreach($mainArray as $miniArray)
{
    if($miniArray['required']==1)
    {
        // Do insert stuff here.
    }
}
```

Or if you want to check whether it exists ANYWHERE in the array before you enter it, a simple boolean should do the trick:

```
$hasRequired=false;
foreach($mainArray as $miniArray)
{
    if($miniArray['required']==1)
    {
        $hasRequired=true;
    }
}

if($hasRequired)
{
    // Do Insert Stuff here.
}
```

Comment: thanx@Fluffehbut,but my question is

Comment: using foreach loop i submit each value and insert it in MySQL db but if [required] => 1 exist in array i don't want to submit any values?

Comment: either use `array_filter` or 2 `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter:

```
$test_array = array(
    array(
        "required"=>0,
        "other_field"=>"value"
    ),
    array(
        "required"=>0,
        "other_field"=>"value"
    ),
    array(
        "required"=>0,
        "other_field"=>"value"
    ),
);

function checkIfRequired($var)
{
    return (is_array($var) && $var['required'] == 1);
}

if(sizeof(array_filter($test_array, "checkIfRequired"))){
    print 'required field exists';
}
else{
    print 'required field does not exist';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_array or in_array function to check the the value of an array. But is_array function is faster and accurate than in_array. 
And here is an example from the php manual . This function will check through whole array .

```
    function myInArray($array, $value, $key){
//loop through the array
foreach ($array as $val) {
  //if $val is an array cal myInArray again with $val as array input
  if(is_array($val)){
    if(myInArray($val,$value,$key))
      return true;
  }
  //else check if the given key has $value as value
  else{
    if($array[$key]==$value)
      return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

}