# checking condition before foreach loop execution php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to check  condition before for loop execution

this is my array

```
$rs=Array (    
    [0] => Array ( 
               [questionID] => 47
               [surveyID] => 51
               [userID] => 31 
               [question_Title] => Choose Any One? 
               [question_Type] => Dropdown 
               [response] => 1.Android 2.Windows 3.Blackberry 
               [required] => 0 
               [add_time] => 0
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
               [questionID] => 48 
               [surveyID] => 51 
               [userID] => 31 
               [question_Title] => Is it? 
               [question_Type] => Bigbox 
               [response] => Yes No 
               [required] => 1 
               [add_time] => 0 
    )    
    [2] => Array ( 
               [questionID] => 129 
               [surveyID] => 51 
               [userID] => 31 
               [question_Title] => sELECT 
               [question_Type] => Single 
               [response] => DFG HBK GHCK HK 
               [required] => 0 
               [add_time] => 0 
    )
)
```

now i want to check if in $rs [required] => 1
then stop over all execution or $rs  traversing using for each loop
rather from above example i want to stop executing first loop also.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I am confused about this part "or $rs traversing using for each loop rather from above example i want to stop executing first loop also.". Can you explain?

Comment: $rs is resulting array from mysql query,i want to submit each subarray values,but if any subarray contains "[required] => 1" then i dont want to submit any  subarray values

Comment: possible duplicate of [check associative array contains value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988258/check-associative-array-contains-value)

Answer (score 0):

Use array_column and achieve this functionality

**Reference**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Lower version array column function code
https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php

```
 <?php

    //assumed records is your array
    $required = array_column($records, 'required');


    if(FALSE===array_search('1', $required))
    {
        //value is not exist then process your loop 
    }
    else
    {
        //required value is 1 then ignore the loop
    }
```

Comment: thanx @sundar,but it requires (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)

Comment: Try for lower version array column https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php code